# Facebook: allowing friends of friends (but not the whole world) to see my posts

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline

So, currently when one posts something on Facebook, the visibility dropdown presents four different privacy options: Public, Friends, Only Me, and Custom (as well as any friend lists one has defined). But there used to be another choice, Friends of Friends, which has been absent for me for ages, maybe one or two years now. What puzzles me is that some of my friends still manage to post stuff with this Friends of Friends visibility — is it simply because they've had it as the default since the days when it still was there for choosing, and they never changed it, or can is still be activated somehow? I sort of really miss it.

Comment: I see "Friends of Friends" as one of the options under "Custom".

Comment: Oh wow. There it is. Still it put the gear icon (for "Custom") on the post after I chose this, but after a page refresh it sure turned into the "Friends of Friends" symbol. Awesome! Thanks, this has been puzzling me for quite a while.

Comment: Okay. I'll make that an answer, then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Friends of Friends" is still there. It's just under the "Custom" option.

Type "Friends of Friends" in the *These people or lists* field. (It will probably be pre-selected for you.)

[image: Custom menu]